# How to make a post request from Android to PHP?

Tags: php, android, android-studio, post, httpurlconnection

I'm using Android Studio / Java for my mobile app project, I have a login activity in which I let the user to put their email and password to log into the app, and once they click the 'submit' button, I fire a `POST` request to post the details to the server (PHP page).

The request hits the PHP page on the server, but the details (email, password) are located in the `$_GET` array instead of the `$_POST` array. That means it is a `GET` request and not a `POST` request.

So this is the code I saw 100s of upvoted and accepted answers that suggested to use for `POST` requests. This code generates a `GET` request and **NOT** a `POST` request, (The parameters received in PHP will be in the `$_GET` array instead of the `$_POST` array):

```
String postData = URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(email, "UTF-8") + "&" + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8");
URL url = new URL("http://localhost/home.php?" + postData);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.connect();
int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine, result = "";
    while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        result += inputLine;
    }
    reader.close();
    return result;
}
```

**Note:** I expect to get a string as a response back from PHP for this post request.

Maybe the fact that I attach the post data to the url as parameters is what makes it a `GET` request? There is another way to attach the data to the request body?

My question is: How do I make a pure `POST` request that will actually post the data to PHP using `HttpURLConnection`? And I will be very clear here: By `POST` request I mean that the variables should not be sent through the url (this is `GET` request), and I will be able to find the posted variables at the famously known `$_POST` array.

How should the `POST` request be made and how to fetch the server's response out of it?

Comment: `new URL("http://localhost/home.php?" + postData)` - You're literally adding the data to the URL yourself here.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson Yes, and that is the problem here. Is there another way to attach the data to the request body? I relatively new to Android. I have a lot of experience with PHP.

Comment: Just to be picky, it's not _another_ way you need since your code doesn't actually set anything in the request body. It sets it in the URL. Check the link I marked as a duplicate. There you can also see the content type you need to set.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson That finally seems to work, i just trying to fetch the response from that request. Thank you.

Comment: Why you did not use Retrofit or something like this libraries?

Comment: @Kuvonchbek Yakubov I prefer to do that with java, especially because i have no background in retrofit, I heard of that. but at the end i really consider to use that because it is not going well with HttpURLConnection.